# Leitura linha a linha de arquivo

Tags: c++

Ola, estou com uma duvida em leitura de arquivo.
Bom estou começando a mexer com arquivos agora, gostaria de saber como fazer leitura linha a linha de um arquivo e apresentar essas linhas, ja pesquisei, porem so acho explicaçoes que misturam C com C++.

Comment: Qual o formato do arquivo? É um arquivo de texto?

Comment: Se for em C++ utilize a classe ifstream ou a fstream. Pesquise na documentação.

Comment: arquivo é formato .txt

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

std::ifstream arquivo( "teste.txt" );     # Seleciona o arquivo
std::string linha;                        # String linha


int main()
{
    while(getline(arquivo, linha))        # Enquanto houver linhas, continuará
    {
         std::cout << linha << std::endl; # Imprime valores, linha a linha
    }

    return 0;
}
```